# Access for Flag/report video using the API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

where can i find access for Flag/report video and send request for "Violent or repulsive content"/"Infringes my rights" using the api?

Answer (score 1):

You POST to this URL : POST `/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/complaints`

From their API Documentation: [YouTube API v2.0 – Complaints](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_complaints)

To add a complaint, you send a `POST` request that identifies the target of the complaint, the user who is making the complaint, and the text of the complaint itself. (The user is identified by the authentication token in the request headers.) The request can also specify the reason for the complaint by using a  tag that has a scheme attribute value of `http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/complaint-reasons.cat`. 
The tag's **term** attribute value must be one of the following terms:

> - **CHILDABUSE** - The video contains acts of child abuse.
> - **DANGEROUS** - The video contains harmful or dangerous acts.
> - **HATE** - The video contains    hateful or abusive content. PORN - The video contains sexual content.
> - **RIGHTS** - The video infringes on the complainant's rights or    copyright.
> - **SPAM**
> - **VIOLENCE** - The video contains violent or repulsive    content.

Here's an example:

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/complaints HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <summary>
    Please ignore this complaint. I'm testing a YouTube API and 
    needed to issue a complaint to test the add complaint function.
    Per the value of the category tag, pretend I am complaining
    about a video that contains violent or repulsive acts.
  </summary>
  <category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/complaint-reasons.cat"
    term="VIOLENCE"/>
</entry>
```